# Is DotNetZip possible to restrucure directories in an archive file

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

My zip file has two levels of directory structure.
I added a new directory at the root using AddDirectoryByName.
Is it possible to move existing directories into the newly create directory?
I like to have the zip file containing 3 levels of directory structure without extracting the zip file.

Current Archive:

```
RootFolder -
           + TopFolder -
                       + SecondFolder
```

Updated Archive file:

```
RootFolder -
           + NewFolder -
                       + TopFolder -
                                   + SecondFolder
```

Comment: Without going into too much detail. If you're just avoiding Disk IO, I believe that it is possible to use .net zip to extract items into a `MemoryStream` and then to put them back into the zip file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to avoid extracting a 500mb file just to add a directly for speed.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. I just had to modify the FileName in all entries.

```
using (ZipFile oZip = ZipFile.Read(sFileZip))
{
     for (int iIdx = 0; iIdx < oZip.Entries.Count; iIdx++)
     {
           string sTmpFileName = oZip[iIdx].FileName;
           oZip[iIdx].FileName = "NewFolder/" + sTmpFileName;
     }
     oZip.Save();
}
```